# how to hide allowed domains from Content Security Policy header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, content-security-policy

I'm trying to hide (not remove), the domains from the CSP (Content-Security-Policy) header
If I remove them the CSP will block the requests from them, I need to hide them so the user cannot see the domains at the F12 netowrk window, is it possible?

```
    <httpProtocol>
 <customHeaders>
  <add name="Content-Security-Policy"
 value="default-src 'self' https://google.com/; style-src 'self' 
'unsafe-inline' https://google.com/; font-src 'self' 
data: https://google.com/; script-src 'self' 
https://google.com/ 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 
'self' https://google.com/" /> 
  </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

Comment: No, it’s not possible

Comment: They are either present or they are not present.  If they are not present they have been removed.

Answer (score 0):

The header (whether HTTP or HTML Meta) needs to to be sent. If it's sent, it can be read.  So no, it's not possible.  The only option is to set a really loose policy that allows anything (which I wouldn't recommend).